# C++ QList in if statement, what is default value?

Tags: c++, qt, if-statement, qlist

I find some code sample with these oddl lines

```
QList<TDataXml *> *newXMLData = input->getValue<QList<TDataXml *>>();
    if(newXMLData) 
    {
        // do things
    }
```

I dont understand `if(newXMLData)`. This is a QList. When should statement be true or false? Why not use Qt isEmpty() method instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(newXMLData)`  checks for nullity, because `newXMLData` is a pointer, and therefore it could point to no object, in which case it's value is `nullptr` (or `NULL` in C++03).

If `newXMLData` is **not** `nullptr`, then it will be `true` and the *if-block* will execute, otherwise `false` and *if-block* will not execute.

It is same as (C++11):

```
if(newXMLData != nullptr) //or if(newXMLData != NULL) in pre C++11
{
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`newXMLData` is *pointer* to `QList` and as such could be initialized to NULL. By testing the pointer in boolean context, you avoid dereferencing a NULL pointer, which would be undefined behaviour.

So in other words, the if statement isn't there to check whether the list is empty or not, it's there to check if the call to `getValue()` method returned a valid pointer. The statement will evaluate to true only if the pointer isn't NULL. Only then you can reliably call `isEmpty()` or any other method of the class the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

if(newXMLData) means the pointer newXMLData points to a valid object or not. you cannot invoke methods of an object if the pointer points to nothing(NULL). So you need to test the pointer is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `newXMLData` is `NULL` or `0`.
But, `newXMLData` needs to be initialized 0 or NULL before if statement.